# How to remove my application link from my account section?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to remove the "My Applications" link from my account section

How to remove that?

Answer (score 2):

Open **oauth.xml** file in your theme's layout folder and comment out these lines:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="oauth">
            <name>OAuth Customer Tokens</name>
            <path>oauth/customer_token</path>
            <label>My Applications</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

Refresh cache and enjoy.

**Note:** If the file **oauth.xml** does not exist in your current theme, you can copy and paste it into your theme from **app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/oauth.xml** path.

Answer (score 1):

Locate file

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/oauth.xml
```

- open the file and there is a block of code that creates the menu item for the Oauth section
- comment it out so it doesn’t show on page

  OAuth Customer Tokens
                  oauth/customer_token
                  My Applications

  ```
  <oauth_customer_token_index translate="label">
      <label>Customer My Account My OAuth Applications</label>
      <update handle="customer_account"/>
      <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
          <block type="oauth/customer_token_list" name="oauth_customer_token_list" template="oauth/customer/token/list.phtml"/>
      </reference>
  </oauth_customer_token_index>
  <!-- EOF My Applications-->
  ```

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Go to ( yourPackage/YourTemplate/customer/account/navigation.phtml )

Step 2: Replace the below line

```
<?php $count = count($links); ?>
```

with

```
<?php $_count = count($_links); /* Add or Remove Account Left Navigation Links Here - 
  */
  unset($_links['account']); /* Account Info */     
  unset($_links['account_edit']); /* Account Info */            
  unset($_links['tags']); /* My Tags */
  unset($_links['invitations']); /* My Invitations */
  unset($_links['reviews']);  /* Reviews */
  unset($_links['wishlist']); /* Wishlist */
  unset($_links['newsletter']); /* Newsletter */
  unset($_links['orders']); /* My Orders */
  unset($_links['address_book']); /* Address */
  unset($_links['enterprise_customerbalance']); /* Store Credit */
  unset($_links['OAuth Customer Tokens']); /* My Applications */
  unset($_links['enterprise_reward']); /* Reward Points */
  unset($_links['giftregistry']); /* Gift Registry */
  unset($_links['downloadable_products']); /* My Downloadable Products */
  unset($_links['recurring_profiles']); /* Recurring Profiles */
  unset($_links['billing_agreements']); /* Billing Agreements */
  unset($_links['enterprise_giftcardaccount']); /* Gift Card Link */
  ?>
```

The above code snippet contains the way to remove all the navigation links. Hope this will help all.

Reference Link: https://github.com/Aproducktion/Magento-Remove-Dashboard-Links